# refer to member variables by name or by index

Tags: c++, class, reference

I am programming a simple class to deal with colours in a small application i am making.

This class would have 4 doubles member variables and it would be desirable to be able to refer to them either by name (i.e: r, g, b, and a) or by index (0 for red, 1 for green and so on).

Also, it would be great to be able to use brace-enclosed initializer lists for initialization.

however, i am not able to figure out an elegant and concise way to code this.

here is my best attempt, it is not pretty. It also doesn't deal with invalid indices.

```
struct Colour{
    double r, g, b, a;
    double& operator[](int i){
        switch(i){
        case 0:
            return r;
            break;
        case 1:
            return g;
            break;
        case 2:
            return b;
            break;
        case 3:
            return a;
            break;
        }
    }
    /* ... */
};
/* ... */
int main(){
    Colour c = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    std::cout << c.g << std::endl;
    c[1] = 10.0;
    std::cout << c.g << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

While this does work, i was wondering if there is a more 
(a) elegant, and
(b) performant (since this application deals mainly with pixel operations) way to do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Elegant is subjective, and there aren't any obvious bottlenecks. Please measure first, then optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks beautiful to me. It could use a default case in the switch statement. I like that you're focused on creating a flexible workflow for the class user, but in general in C++ there ain't no such thing as a free lunch. If you want a more options, your class is going to be more complicated.

However, SINCE YOU ASKED. If elegance to you means keeping your class definitions concise...

```
// C++'11
struct Colour
{
    double v[4];

    double& r = v[0];
    double& g = v[1];
    double& b = v[2];
    double& a = v[3];

    double& operator[](int i)
    {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < 4);  // #include <assert.h>
        return v[i];
    }
};


void test()
{
    Colour c{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    std::cout << c.b << std::endl;
}
```

Issues I have with this:

```
Colour c{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };  // does not compile (good!)

double x = 5.0;
Colour c{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, x };  // compiles (...bad)
```

Btw, the assert throws a helpful exception in debug mode but the check is removed (via a flag) when compiling in release mode.

**If it were me, I would go with your code and add bounds checking.**

For performance, at this point the only thing you need to concern yourself with is not using inefficient algorithms. Later on, if you've done profiling and this class is a bottleneck (LOL), we can try to optimize it. Btw, code brevity and optimization are not friends.

Comment: Ahh thank you! that's just what i was looking for, i can't believe i didn't think of that

Comment: This is such a smart way of allowing both index and by name access... I have to agree with the previous comment: I can't believe i didn't think of that. For the constructor, wouldn't using an std::array solve that problem?

Comment: On second thought, this has a big problem: the references take up a lot of space. So you cannot use this for the pixels of an image, because it would enlarge every pixel by the size of the references. It would be nice if those could be only "symbolic references".

Comment: I agree that the space is an issue. 32 bytes -> 48 bytes per instance (32-bit program) or 32 bytes -> 64 bytes (64-bit program). This is important not because of space concerns, but because at this level, physical proximity affects the performance boosts from caching. However, I didn't mention that because we're not supposed to care about performance right now, gosh dangit!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an pre-C++11 enumerator if there are limited number of well defined integer like items.  You enumerators can be RED=1, GREEN=2, BLUE=3, etc.  So your code will be much more readable but still maintain it's integer efficiency.

The only time you would need to convert to characters and/or strings is if you want to input or output your data to, say, a file.  In that case you just have a converting function.  But presumably, input/output is not the bulk of where these values are being used so the converting function's performance would be less of a concern.

Comment: i like this idea but I'm not sure it works for me, thank you though

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on this which builds on @HumphreyWinnebago solution, but tries to solve the increase in size. The idea is to use a union with an array and an unnamed struct. In this way you can access the struct elements by name and the array elements by index.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

template<typename T>
union Colour {
    std::array<T,4> v;
    struct { T r,g,b,a; };

    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        assert(i < 4);
        return v[i];
    }
};

int main() {
    Colour<uint8_t> c{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << int(c.b) << "\n";
    std::cout << int(c[1]) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof c << "\n";

    Colour<double> d{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    std::cout << d.b << "\n";
    std::cout << d[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof d << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I fear that this unfortunately heavily relies on implementation specific alignment of structs, but nevertheless I believe it could be an interesting solution.